# Is it possible to create custom extensions for Microsoft Test Manager?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I want to create a custom extension, i.e. to add a button to the test runner in MTM. Is it possible to do so, like with a VSIX extension, in the same (or similar) way as can be done with Visual Studio?

More info:

What I want to create is a plugin for MTM, that will add a button to the Test Case editing window (under the Testing Center | Plan section), that when pressed will do something (e.g. generate some code).

**UPDATE**
I looked at what TestScribe does, and after installing it, a third *center* is added (after "Testing Center" and "Lab Center") - Tools (see below):
[image]

I will be very happy, if I can somehow add a tool much like ***Documentation*** above.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize like [Test Scrib](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e79e4a0f-f670-47c2-9b8a-3b6f664bf4ae) on MTM, you can get the code on [Codeplex](https://testscribeextended.codeplex.com/), but I don't know if you can customize the panel screen of the runner... Give more detail what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of looking at Test Scribe. Unfortunately, the code you linked to is for another tool that tries to duplicate TS's functionality, but it is a standalone win-forms app, not Test Scribe itself, or a similar extension.